# Issue trying to build LLVM and clang

Tags: linux, makefile, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to build LLVM and clang on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04). I followed the instructions on http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html up to step 6 (build LLVM and clang). When I make, I get a whole load of warnings about potentially incompatibly plugin versions (to do with dragonegg?). But the whole thing fails with these messages:

```
llvm[2]: Linking Debug+Asserts executable llvm-tblgen
/usr/bin/ld: /home/peter/llvm/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/llvm-tblgen: hidden symbol `llvm::Type::~Type()' isn't defined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/peter/llvm/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/llvm-tblgen] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/llvm/build/utils/TableGen'
make[1]: *** [TableGen/.makeall] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/llvm/build/utils'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

So any help you could give me would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Be careful if you are trying to install vmkit as well for Java support. You need JDK from Oracle, not OpenJDK. If you uninstall OpenJDK, ant is removed, so reisntall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up deleting the llvm folder and checking everything out again, and it worked, so I'm just putting it down to bad timing.

Comment: Next time, try waiting an hour or two, and then doing a 'make update'. The version of llvm you check out is the bleeding edge, and sometimes it doesn't build correctly. (I have also had this issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the existing LLVM packages, as provided by your distributions.

This [askubuntu question about LLVM 3.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141597/llvm-clang-3-1-libc) could be relevant.

And you should at least do `apt-get build-dep llvm-3.1-dev` to ensure all dependencies are available.

You could also ask help on some LLVM related mailing list.